# R code chunks no longer working when using markdown in visual studio code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, markdown

I have been using studio visual code to create markdown files and everything has been fine until today.

All the chunks I have created no longer link to R. They are not displayed in R language format/colours etc. and I can not run the code within a chunk directly in R interactive. When I knit to html, the code is displayed as plain text as if it has not been processed by R at all.

I have been using pandoc to render and it was fine. I was messing around with shortcuts today and after creating a code chunk using shift/command/I all of the code chunks changed to plain text and will not compile.

Please help this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Perhaps you could explore if VScode was updated in any way, perhaps without you knowing? Or perhaps the plugin for R interface? Or both?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [visual Markdown editing issues](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22visual+markdown+editing%22), and possibly file a new one